# Unity XML Configuration with Generics

Tags: xml, unity-container

Having a bit of a headache with Unity XML configuration and generics.  I have these files:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {}

public class OrderRepository : IRepository { }

public class DispatchOrderProcess
{
     public DispatchOrderProcess(IRepository<Order> repository) { }
}
```

I would like to inject the Order Repository into the DispatchOrderProcess class using Unity XML configuration.  So far I have something like so:

```
            <type name="OrderRespository" type="Company.Project.Core.Interfaces.IRepository`1, Company.Project.Core" mapTo="Company.Project.Core.Repositories.OrderRepository, Company.Project.Core" />

            <type name="DispatchOrderProccess" type="Company.Project.Core.Interfaces.ISendAlertsProcess, Company.Project.Core" mapTo="Company.Project.Core.Processes.SendAlertsProcess, Company.Project.Core">
                <typeConfig>
                    <constructor>
                        <param name="orderRepository" parameterType="Company.Project.Core.Interfaces.IRepository`1, Company.Project.Core">
                            <dependency name="OrderRespository"/>
                        </param>
                    </constructor>
                </typeConfig>
            </type>
        </types>
    </container>
</containers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...and your problem is?

I have done some stuff with generics quite recently though and I had some trouble with the syntax. Apparently I neaded to tell unity what the typeof T was, something like:

```
type="Company.Project.Core.Interfaces.IRepository`1 [[System.String, mscorlib version 2.0.0.0...etc]], Company.Project.Core"
```

does this help you out in any way?

Comment: Sorry, should have been a little more descriptive!  Your solution worked perfectly, thanks :)